# Returning Callback from Angular, Link or Controller Directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I want to create a table directive, I wanted to know how to pass a callback to for example: "Calling a delete function that is not in the Controller", I was wanting to pass as a callback using parameters, but for some time I am hitting my head with it. When I can return the callback through the "link" I can not return the values, and the controller can not.

[Imagem when I use link , but don't back values of callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hYX4.png)

[Image when I use Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWhYB.png)

> View DashBoard

```
<div crud-table options='vm.options' callback='vm.myCallBack(response)'></div>
```

> Controller DashBoard

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('senhalivre')
        .controller('DashboardMikrotikCtrl', DashboardMikrotikCtrl);

    DashboardMikrotikCtrl.$inject = [];

    function DashboardMikrotikCtrl() {

        var vm = this;

        vm.myCallBack = myCallBack;

        vm.options = {
            enabled : true,
            msg : 'DashBoard',
            // Configs etc..... 
        }

        //////////////////

        function myCallBack(response){

            console.log('Callback !!! ');
            console.log(response);

        }

    }

})();
```

> Directive

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('senhalivre')
        .directive('crudTable', crudTable);

    crudTable.$inject = [];

    function crudTable() {

        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: crudTableCtrl,
            templateUrl : './views/crud/crudTable.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: link,
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                options : '=',
                callback : '&callback'
            }
        };

        return directive;

        ////////////////

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.vm.callback({test : 'something'});
            // Work

        }

    }

    crudTableCtrl.$inject = [];

    function crudTableCtrl() {

        var vm = this;

        vm.callback({test : 'something'});
        // :( 

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the property 'response' in the parameter-object when calling the callback:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
 scope.vm.callback({response: 'some response text'});
}
```

or

```
function crudTableCtrl() {
    this.callback({response: 'something'});
}
```